# Since php does not support private classes, what naming conventions are there to denote them?

Tags: php

Since php does not support private classes, what naming conventions are there to denote them?

I've seen people use classes starting with underscore `_` but have been told to keep away from such standard since its been from the old PHP 4 days.

Any alternatives?

Comment: How can you have a private class? A private method, which can be called from within the class alone is one thing, but if a class were to be _private_, how would you even instantiate it?

Comment: I still use _ (underscore) for private and __ for magic / reserved things.  Heard of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)?  Looser languages and IDEs you don't see much of that anymore.  I respect devs that name things well.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have private classes but if you're using PHP7+ you can use anonymous classes.

```
class MyClass {

    private function getPrivateClass() {
        return new class {
            protected $property = "I'm a private class";

            public function getProperty() {
                return $this->property;
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm interested in any naming conventions used for private classes.

Comment: @BasilMusa Private classes are not a common pattern in PHP (in part because it's not supported by the language). I've actually never heard of it used in PHP at all. As such I don't think there is any naming convention.